# Populate RadComboBox from enum list in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, radcombobox

I found some topics "How to bind a combobox from enum list", but my problem is that I try to use MVVM arhitecture and let my View (xaml) clear as you see below:

**part of View (xaml.cs):**

```
public partial class GreenCertificatesStockForm : Erp.Core.Wpf.BaseWindow
    {
        private Models.GreenCertificatesGroupModel model;
        public GreenCertificatesStockForm()
        {
            model = new Models.GreenCertificatesGroupModel();

            this.DataContext = model;

            InitializeComponent();

            model.LoadForm(); // propose some dates for my form
            model.RequestClose += () => { Close(); };
        }
    }
```

**part of View (xaml) my RadComboBox:**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Name="certificatesTypeRadComboBox"
                      Margin="5 2 0 2"  Width="150"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding CertificatesTypeEnum , Mode=TwoWay, 
                                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                                ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                                                NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                      ItemSource="{Binding }"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding }"
                      telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office_Blue" BorderBrush="#FF707070" Background="#FFDDDDDD" 
                                >

            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

So, my Enum list is created in my **ViewModel (class.cs)** as:

```
public enum CertificatesTypeEnum {
            Estimat = 1,
            Calculat = 2,
            Facturat = 3
            }
```

I need to display in my RadComboBox all Values of the Enum and by selectedValue to save the specific Key of selection in DB (this with a parameter). How can I display the values from ViewModel into ComboBox (View)?

I know can do something like :

```
var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CertificatesTypeEnum)).Cast<CertificatesTypeEnum>().Select(i => new ComboboxItem()
        { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(gender), i), Value = (int)i}).ToArray<ComboboxItem>();
        //Add the items to your combobox (given that it's called comboBox1)
        RadComboBoxName.Items.AddRange(items);
```

but this must be made in xaml.cs file (and I don't want this solution), because in ViewModel the combobox are not recognised and will be not found.

In short : display Values of Enum list from ViewModel class in xaml file.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987099/1136211) for how to bind the ItemsSource to a collection of all enum values. In addition, your view model should have a property for the selected enum value, to which you would bind the SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just call the `Enum.GetValues` method in the view model? This is MVVM:

```
public class GreenCertificatesGroupModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CertificatesTypeEnum> EnumValues
    {
        get
        {
            var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CertificatesTypeEnum)).Cast<CertificatesTypeEnum>();
            return list;
        }

    }

    private CertificatesTypeEnum _selectedItem;

    public CertificatesTypeEnum SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { _selectedItem = value; }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnumValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: this work, values appear on my combobox, but how can I save the specific Id of selected value? Because in the List, I save only values (Enum.GetValues). I tried something like int Id = (int)CertificatesTypeEnum.SelectedItem, but doesn't work

Comment: In the view model, you would do: `int x = (int)_selectedItem;`

Comment: in xaml is a problem. I need to use SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}" to return the value, this is ok, I can save the "Id" in my database, but the problem is if I use SelectedValue or SelectedItem, after select one item from combobox, all items from list dissapear, are hidden, but the values are there. If I don't use one of these 2 properties, can't use the value in code, every time return 0.

Comment: You should use SelectedItem and bind to an enum property as per my example...don't involve SelectedValue.

Comment: Done. But it's a little strange. First, use SelectItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}", then in my datatable I update the column's value: dr["Type"] = selectedItem; What is strange, property selectedItem have a string value [example "estimate"], but to dr["Type"] which is int, transfer the key of "estimate" value, from Enum list. I don't know how this is possible, maybe due of EnumValues (public IEnumerable<CertificatesTypeEnum> EnumValues), the list return the Key of selected value.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. This question was about how to display enum values in a RadComboBox using MVVM and I believe it has been answered now.